# How to test Express API with Chai to 3rd party endpoints that 404?

Tags: express, mocha.js, chai, chai-http

I really don't know exactly how to phrase my question. But I can explain what's going on.

**server.js** (affected route definition)

```js
app.get("/api/users/:id", users.getUser);
```

**users.js** (users route file)

```js
getUser: asyncMiddleware(async (req, res, next) => {
  const { data } = await axios.get(
    `https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users/${req.params.id}`
  );
  const userData = pruneData([data]);
  res.status(200).json(userData);
})
```

**asyncMiddleware.js** (catch async errors)

```js
const asyncMiddleware = fn => (req, res, next) => {
  Promise.resolve(fn(req, res, next)).catch(next);
};

export default asyncMiddleware;
```

**users.test.js**

```js
import chai from "chai";
import chaiHttp from "chai-http";
import app from "../../src/server/server";

const expect = chai.expect;
chai.use(chaiHttp);

describe("Users API tests", () => {
  it("should return a 500 server error", done => {
    chai
      .request(app)
      .get("/api/users/11") // outside the range or contacts
      .end((err, res) => {
        expect(res).to.have.status(404);
        done();
      });
  });
});
```

**Test output**

```js
Error: Request failed with status code 404
    at createError (/Users/XXXX/node_modules/axios/lib/core/createError.js:16:15)
    at settle (/Users/XXXX/node_modules/axios/lib/core/settle.js:17:12)
    at IncomingMessage.handleStreamEnd (/Users/XXXX/node_modules/axios/lib/adapters/http.js:237:11)
    at IncomingMessage.emit (events.js:205:15)
    at endReadableNT (_stream_readable.js:1154:12)
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:84:9)
    1) should return a 500 server error

    1 failing

    1) Users API tests
    should return a 500 server error:

    Uncaught AssertionError: expected { Object (_events, _eventsCount, ...) } to have status code 404 but got 500
    + expected - actual

    -500
    +404

    at status (tests/routes/users.test.js:43:29)
    at Test.Request.callback (node_modules/superagent/lib/node/index.js:716:12)
    at IncomingMessage.<anonymous> (node_modules/superagent/lib/node/index.js:916:18)
    at endReadableNT (_stream_readable.js:1154:12)
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:84:9)
```

The actual returned response status from the `jsonplaceholder.typicode.com` website is a 404 when you give an id outside the range. This is where the 404 is coming from, but why is the test not catching that and instead sending a 500 from my own server?

If I change the test to check for status 500 all tests pass but I still have the `Error: Request failed with status code 404` in the test output.

BTW - I have 10 other tests that pass without any issue, this is the only one of its kind in my suite so far.

Comment: Possibly because axios is throwing an error and it is not caught for the 404 from the external site. I dont see where in your middleware or anywhere else a 500 would be returned based on your server

Comment: I’m pretty sure the 500 comes from the unhandled 404

Answer (score 0):

Ok, for some reason or another the asyncMiddleware that I was wrapping around my async calls was not returning correctly.

I've moved to using the try/catch method and sending the status from err.response and it seems to be working.

```js
getUser: async (req, res, next) => {
  try {
    const { data } = await axios.get(
      `https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users/${req.params.id}`
    );
    const userData = pruneData([data]);
    res.status(200).json(userData);
  } catch (err) {
    res.status(err.response.status).json({ err });
  }
}
```

Which actually returns the 404 now.